# Hospital Payment Plan - FSA account

Tags: united-states, health-insurance, fsa, eligible-expenses

I have a large hospital expense coming up in the next week and was planning on signing up for a monthly payment plan.

Currently,  I am not enrolled in FSA account for the 2019-2020 period.  We are in open enrollment now and I have opted to add funds to my account for the 2020-2021 period that doesn't start until next month (two weeks after my hospital stay).

Can I use my 2020 FSA funds to pay for a monthly hospital bill that technically started in the 2019 period?

Comment: Have you asked your plan administrator? It may depend on the type of service or what the plan allows. The default rule is that you can only use FSA for expenses incurred in the plan year, but there are some exceptions (i.e. orthodontia can be paid for based on service date or billed date, which essentially allows you to be reimbursed for monthly payments across several years).